# JavaFX snapshot doesn't capture background

Tags: java, javafx

Attempting to use a JavaFX [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html)'s [`snapshot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.util.Callback-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) method to capture a "Background" element. I'm specifically interested in a node's background (as the name suggests).

If I setup my scene with a `StackPane`, and the background literally being an `ImageView` underneath what I'm trying to display, then everything works fine. But if I use the more intuitive `setBackground` function of a node, and try to capture a snapshot, it (the background) doesn't show up.

For example this works as expected, if you do `getBackgroundNode().snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null)`:

```
private Node getBackgroundNode() {
    ImageView background = new ImageView(new Image("https://www.yamaha-motor.ca/images/pages/products/units/MC/action/2016_FZ_07_2_l.jpg"));
    Rectangle2D viewport = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, 1080, 720);
    background.setViewport(viewport);

    return background;
}
```

However, the below method doesn't show me the background when I call the `snapshot` method.

```
private Node getBackgroundNode() {
    Image background = new Image("https://www.yamaha-motor.ca/images/pages/products/units/mc/action/2016_fz_07_2_l.jpg");

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(background, null, null, null, null)));

    stack.setPrefSize(1080, 720);

    return stack;
}
```

Is this simply a feature of the `snapshot` method? I took a look at `SnapshotParameters` and there aren't any obvious settings that would allow me to capture the background.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `StackPane` is usually not set until it has been layouted. Therefore you create a snapshot of a `Node` of size `(0, 0)`. A properly layouted `Node` includes the background. You could set the size of the `StackPane` by calling `resize` before taking the snapshot:

```
Node backgroundNode = getBackgroundNode();
backgroundNode.resize(1080, 720);
backgroundNode.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
```